# How to read all files that are hosted by a file server

Tags: c#, html, streamreader, static-files, fileserver

## Desription

I am using `FileServerOptions` to host some files.

The `EnableDirectoryBrowsing` option is enabled so I can view the files through a browser.

I would like to get a list of all the files within the directory (preferably recursively).

## Code

### Server

The following code is used to serve the files.

```cs
public void Run(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var serviceProvider = IocStartup.BuildServiceProvider();
         
    config.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(serviceProvider);
    
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    
    var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileSystem  = new PhysicalFileSystem(SystemConfiguration.ConfigDirectory),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Config"),
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
    };

    appBuilder.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
}
```

## Client

The following code can be used to read in the contents of an index file.

```cs
var indexFileStream = WebRequest.Create(indexFilePath).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
if (indexFileStream != null)
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(indexFileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    var indexFileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader.Close();
}
```

## Output (Index File)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Index of /Config/MainFolder/SubFolder</title>
  <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", "Helvetica Neue", 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;}
    header h1 {
        font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Helvetica Neue", 'RobotoLight', "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;}
    #index {
        border-collapse: separate; 
        border-spacing: 0; 
        margin: 0 0 20px; }
    #index th {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #a0a0a0;
        text-align: center; }
    #index td { padding: 3px 10px; }
    #index th, #index td {
        border-right: 1px #ddd solid;
        border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
        border-left: 1px transparent solid;
        border-top: 1px transparent solid;
        box-sizing: border-box; }
    #index th:last-child, #index td:last-child {
        border-right: 1px transparent solid; }
    #index td.length, td.modified { text-align:right; }
    a { color:#1ba1e2;text-decoration:none; }
    a:hover { color:#13709e;text-decoration:underline; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="main">
    <header><h1>Index of <a href="/">/</a><a href="/Config/">Config/</a><a href="/Config/MainFolder/">MainFolder/</a><a href="/Config/MainFolder/SubFolder/">SubFolder/</a></h1></header>
    <table id="index" summary="The list of files in the given directory.  Column headers are listed in the first row.">
    <thead>
      <tr><th abbr="Name">Name</th><th abbr="Size">Size</th><th abbr="Modified">Last Modified</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="file">
        <td class="name"><a href="File1.xml">File1.xml</a></td>
        <td class="length">10,117</td>
        <td class="modified">6/16/2023 12:08:00 PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="file">
        <td class="name"><a href="File2.xml">File2.xml</a></td>
        <td class="length">10,782</td>
        <td class="modified">6/16/2023 12:08:00 PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="file">
        <td class="name"><a href="File3.xml">File3.xml</a></td>
        <td class="length">5,359</td>
        <td class="modified">6/16/2023 12:08:00 PM</td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

## Question

I know I can manually parse the index file to get a list of files.

However, I would like to know if there are any more robust / built-in functionality for getting a list of files in this circumstance.

It would be especially helpful if it could be done recursively.

Comment: What *do* you want to return and how do you want to use it? Returning the index *is* the standard way of returning static file contents. That's what all browsers and file managers understand. If you want something else you'll have to write your own code, eg your own controller, to return what you want.

Comment: Do you want to display the results to humans or use them in another application or script? In the second case it would be better to return a JSON list of the file URLs and any extra information you want, eg size or dates

Comment: Ultimately I want to get the contents of each of the files (recursively) within a given folder.
To do that I need to get a list of their paths, which I know can be manually parsed from the index file(s).
I would like to know if there is a built-in method for doing this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to use it in another application

Comment: In that case, return a JSON string. You can get all files with `Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern,SearchOptions.AllFiles)`. This will return all files that match the pattern in that path, recursively. Same with `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` which returns `FileInfo` objects instead of paths. What do you want to return though? I suspect the *relative* paths? As URLs or just paths?

Comment: You can get the relative path  of a file relative to a folder with [Path.GetRelativePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried using `Directory.GetFiles` but it threw `System.ArgumentException: 'URI formats are not supported.'`